# Known plaintext and encrypted text, what method or cipher is being used?

Tags: encryption, decryption

I have the plaintext and the encrypted(?) output.
Maybe you guys know which method is used for this encrytion.
I was thinking about Base64 because of the "=" termination, but i'm not sure because of the slashs.

Any idea?

Plaintext: 12345

Decrypted: /A/P9nt/Ig/Ll/Z8=

The decrypted password was stored as a value in windows registry as reg_sz.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you look up the data type? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types

Comment: Yes i checked it already, but no idea how this should help :-(

Comment: *Decrypted*? Decrypted is the same as the plain text. If you mean *encrypted*, please edit your question.